# Regex that accept custom format

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate a string that can have the following format:

```
0000000000-0000
1001
1001-1
```

Possible format that should validate

```
XXXXXXXXXX-XXXX
XXXX 
XXXX-X
```

Only digits are required in the string and the - sign is optional.
At least 4 digits (up to 10) then optional - sign then a max of 4 more digits (also optional).

I tried `\d{4,}-?\d*` but as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/1qYpHu/1) it's matching `1232-test` and it shouldn't be. The whole string must be numeric and optional `-` sign, nothing else.

All the above should pass the regex but nothing else.
I could try all day long to come up with something but since I never dig into regex I turn to you guys.

Comment: Does [`^\d{4,10}(?:-\d{1,4})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zhskHC/1) work for you? Also, can the entries end in `-` such as `0123-`?

Comment: You need to add your current regular expression to the question. How else do you except us to help with finding what has to be changed in it? Or do you simply want someone else to do your work for you?

Comment: Did you "try all day long"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `^\d{4,10}(?:-\d{1,4})?$`

https://regex101.com/r/00GCtH/1

Formatted

```
 ^                             # Begin of string
 \d{4,10}                      # Required 4 to 10 digits
 (?:                           # Optional dash and 1 to 4 digits
      - \d{1,4} 
 )?
 $                             # End of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex is OK, just add the beginning and end of the line to it:

```
^\d{4,}-?\d*$
```

However, if you want to restrict it to your upper limits (up to 10, followed by up to 4) then add them:

```
^\d{4,10}-?\d{0,4}$
```